# UIButton detect press and hold, along with "gesture recognizer"?

Tags: ios, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer, gesture

I'm trying to figure out how to detect a press and hold, as well as a gesture recognizer on a `UIButton`.

I did search around and didn't find exactly what I was looking for. 
Here is a quick gif to see what I'm trying to do: http://blitzzmobile.com/files/button.gif
(in the case of the gif the user holds on the "5" button and drags up to select the addition button.)
If anyone could give me a tip or point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit** : Also, I'd like to know if its possible to detect the location of the "drag" and animate accordingly. (Example: if someone drags half the distance to show the new menu, the menu animates accordingly) & the method to detect the drag release, not from the `UIButton`, but when the user lifts his finger after touching the `UIButton` and dragging, an action is called, is this possible?

Comment: Very slick! Dividing by six or subtracting four may become slightly challenging, though :)

Comment: How about using `UIView` with different `UIGestureRecognizer`s instead of `UIButton`? I think, that way you could add several gestures to your views and listen for each separately.

Comment: @fahri-azimov thanks, instead I just checked which button was highlighted at the time the gesture recognition and animated accordingly.

Comment: Investigate the `UIPanGestureRegognizer` to drag something. Reset the frame and the translation on each call to the `.changed` gesture recognizer.

Answer (score 0):

For whoever might benefit from this, here is what I did:

```
    -(IBAction) yourAction:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
         if(yourbutton.highlighted){
              //Do your animation/setup here.
         }
    }
```